# Wildcard matching in Java

Tags: java, regex, wildcard

I'm writing a simple debugging program that takes as input simple strings that can contain stars to indicate a wildcard match-any

```
*.wav  // matches <anything>.wav
(*, a) // matches (<anything>, a)
```

I thought I would simply take that pattern, escape any regular expression special characters in it, then replace any `\\*` back to `.*`. And then use a regular expression matcher.

But I can't find any Java function to escape a regular expression. The best match I could find is `Pattern.quote`, which however just puts `\Q` and `\E` at the begin and end of the string.

Is there anything in Java that allows you to simply do that wildcard matching without you having to implement the algorithm from scratch?

Comment: `Pattern.quote()` and the rest of your approach should work just fine. What are you seeing which suggests otherwise?

Comment: @MattBall I will end up with `\Q(.*, a)\E` which will not match `(foo, a)`, because `foo` does not match the literal `.*`.

Comment: I think I misunderstand what the end goal is. You get a string like `*.wav`. What's going to happen to it?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i simply want to match it against text.

Comment: So your input is your regex? Why do you need to escape anything?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the input is any string, but with only '*' having special meaning. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#wildcard-matching

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Using A Simple Regex**

One of this method's benefits is that we can easily add tokens besides `*` (see **Adding Tokens** at the bottom).

Search: `[^*]+|(\*)`

- The left side of the `|` matches any chars that are not a star
- The right side captures all stars to Group 1
- If Group 1 is empty: replace with `\Q` + Match + `E`
- If Group 1 is set: replace with `.*`

Here is some working code (see the output of the [online demo](https://ideone.com/uzw3NZ)).

Input: `audio*2012*.wav`

Output: `\Qaudio\E.*\Q2012\E.*\Q.wav\E`

```
String subject = "audio*2012*.wav";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^*]+|(\\*)");
Matcher m = regex.matcher(subject);
StringBuffer b= new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    if(m.group(1) != null) m.appendReplacement(b, ".*");
    else m.appendReplacement(b, "\\\\Q" + m.group(0) + "\\\\E");
}
m.appendTail(b);
String replaced = b.toString();
System.out.println(replaced);
```

**Adding Tokens**

Suppose we also want to convert the wildcard `?`, which stands for a single character, by a dot. We just add a capture group to the regex, and exclude it from the matchall on the left:

Search: `[^*?]+|(\*)|(\?)`

In the replace function we the add something like:

```
else if(m.group(2) != null) m.appendReplacement(b, ".");
```

Comment: this looks best so far. waiting for someone to perhaps find a simplier solution still. Thanks!

Comment: What I like is that if you want to add the single-character `?` token used in wildcard matching, it's a piece of cake: `[^*?]+|(\*)|(\?)`, then in the replace function we add `if(m.group(2) != null) m.appendReplacement(b, ".");` (as the dot is a single character)

Comment: Doesn't `wildcardSpec.replaceAll("[^*]+", "\\\\Q$0\\\\E").replaceAll("\\*+", ".*")` work aswell?

Comment: Sure, if you want to chain two replacements. Just giving you something that's easy to read and especially to maintain in case your requirements change. It's a variation of a technique explained in detail here: [Regex-matching or replacing... except when...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/) I had a lot of fun with that answer btw :) Ah, also, added a section about Adding Tokens at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Thanks Johannes. :) See you next time.

Comment: Looking for something that mimics Lucene's semantics, which includes the ability to escape wildcard characters, so that `Wal*mart` would become `\QWal\E.*\Qmart\E` but `Wal\*mart` would become either `\QWal*mart\E` or `\QWal\E\*\Qmart\E`

Answer (score 21):

There is small utility method in Apache Commons-IO library: org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils#wildcardMatch(), which you can use without intricacies of the regular expression.

API documentation could be found in: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#wildcardMatch(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 17):

Just escape everything - no harm will come of it.

```
    String input = "*.wav";
    String regex = ("\\Q" + input + "\\E").replace("*", "\\E.*\\Q");
    System.out.println(regex); // \Q\E.*\Q.wav\E
    System.out.println("abcd.wav".matches(regex)); // true
```

Or you can use character classes:

```
    String input = "*.wav";
    String regex = input.replaceAll(".", "[$0]").replace("[*]", ".*");
    System.out.println(regex); // .*[.][w][a][v]
    System.out.println("abcd.wav".matches(regex)); // true
```

It's easier to "escape" the characters by putting them in a character class, as almost all characters lose any special meaning when in a character class. Unless you're expecting weird file names, this will work.

Comment: Hmm, why didn't I think of that. It seems too easy. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. Java complains "Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 3
\f\o\o". Apparently it only allows to escape a limited set of characters: "It is an error to use a backslash prior to any alphabetic character that does not denote an escaped construct; these are reserved for future extensions to the regular-expression language.".

Comment: Did you copy paste? This code runs without error. I can only assume that you coded `replaceAll()` instead of `replace()` for the second method call. Is that what happened?

Comment: I used your initial solution. The updated answer should work aswell.

Comment: Wouldn't this break if the text being searched contains "\E"?  You could use Pattern.quote(String) to avoid that.

Comment: @twm Yes, but that isn't relevant to the question, which specifically excludes calling `Pattern.quote()` and wants only to have simple regex chars like dots treated as literals and the asterisk treated as a "wildcard" (`.*` in regex).

Comment: Ah, sorry - I missed the part about excluding Pattern.quote().

Comment: probably you want to replace ? with \w, what is commonly used in wildcards

Answer (score 2):

**Regex While Accommodating A DOS/Windows Path**

Implementing the Quotation escape characters `\Q` and `\E` is probably the best approach. However, since a backslash is typically used as a DOS/Windows file separator, a "`\E`" sequence within the path could effect the pairing of `\Q` and `\E`. While accounting for the `*` and `?` wildcard tokens, this situation of the backslash could be addressed in this manner:

Search: `[^*?\\]+|(\*)|(\?)|(\\)`

Two new lines would be added in the replace function of the "Using A Simple Regex" example to accommodate the new search pattern. The code would still be "Linux-friendly". As a method, it could be written like this:

```
public String wildcardToRegex(String wildcardStr) {
    Pattern regex=Pattern.compile("[^*?\\\\]+|(\\*)|(\\?)|(\\\\)");
    Matcher m=regex.matcher(wildcardStr);
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        if(m.group(1) != null) m.appendReplacement(sb, ".*");
        else if(m.group(2) != null) m.appendReplacement(sb, ".");     
        else if(m.group(3) != null) m.appendReplacement(sb, "\\\\\\\\");
        else m.appendReplacement(sb, "\\\\Q" + m.group(0) + "\\\\E");
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Code to demonstrate the implementation of this method could be written like this:

```
String s = "C:\\Temp\\Extra\\audio??2012*.wav";
System.out.println("Input: "+s);
System.out.println("Output: "+wildcardToRegex(s));
```

This would be the generated results:

```
Input: C:\Temp\Extra\audio??2012*.wav
Output: \QC:\E\\\QTemp\E\\\QExtra\E\\\Qaudio\E..\Q2012\E.*\Q.wav\E
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Quotation escape characters: `\\Q and \\E` - everything between them is treated as literal and not considered to be part of the regex to be evaluated. Thus this code should work:

```
    String input = "*.wav";
    String regex = "\\Q" + input.replace("*", "\\E.*?\\Q") + "\\E";

    // regex = "\\Q\\E.*?\\Q.wav\\E"
```

Note that your * wildcard might also be best matched only against word characters using \w depending on how you want your wildcard to behave(?)

Comment: prefer `Pattern.quote()` in case input contains `\E`

Answer (score 1):

```java
  // The main function that checks if two given strings match. The pattern string  may contain
  // wildcard characters
  default boolean matchPattern(String pattern, String str) {

    // If we reach at the end of both strings, we are done
    if (pattern.length() == 0 && str.length() == 0) return true;

    // Make sure that the characters after '*' are present in str string. This function assumes that
    // the pattern string will not contain two consecutive '*'
    if (pattern.length() > 1 && pattern.charAt(0) == '*' && str.length() == 0) return false;

    // If the pattern string contains '?', or current characters of both strings match
    if ((pattern.length() > 1 && pattern.charAt(0) == '?')
        || (pattern.length() != 0 && str.length() != 0 && pattern.charAt(0) == str.charAt(0)))
      return matchPattern(pattern.substring(1), str.substring(1));

    // If there is *, then there are two possibilities
    // a: We consider current character of str string
    // b: We ignore current character of str string.
    if (pattern.length() > 0 && pattern.charAt(0) == '*')
      return matchPattern(pattern.substring(1), str) || matchPattern(pattern, str.substring(1));
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("w*ks", "weeks"); // Yes
    test("we?k*", "weekend"); // Yes
    test("g*k", "gee"); // No because 'k' is not in second
    test("*pqrs", "pqrst"); // No because 't' is not in first
    test("abc*bcd", "abcdhghgbcd"); // Yes
    test("abc*c?d", "abcd"); // No because second must have 2 instances of 'c'
    test("*c*d", "abcd"); // Yes
    test("*?c*d", "abcd"); // Yes
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lucene has classes that provide this capability, with additional support for backslash as an escape character. `?` matches a single character, `1` matches 0 or more characters, `\` escapes the following character. Supports Unicode code points. Supposed to be fast but I haven't tested.

```
CharacterRunAutomaton characterRunAutomaton;
boolean matches;
characterRunAutomaton = new CharacterRunAutomaton(WildcardQuery.toAutomaton(new Term("", "Walmart")));
matches = characterRunAutomaton.run("Walmart"); // true
matches = characterRunAutomaton.run("Wal*mart"); // false
matches = characterRunAutomaton.run("Wal\\*mart"); // false
matches = characterRunAutomaton.run("Waldomart"); // false
characterRunAutomaton = new CharacterRunAutomaton(WildcardQuery.toAutomaton(new Term("", "Wal*mart")));
matches = characterRunAutomaton.run("Walmart"); // true
matches = characterRunAutomaton.run("Wal*mart"); // true
matches = characterRunAutomaton.run("Wal\\*mart"); // true
matches = characterRunAutomaton.run("Waldomart"); // true
characterRunAutomaton = new CharacterRunAutomaton(WildcardQuery.toAutomaton(new Term("", "Wal\\*mart")));
matches = characterRunAutomaton.run("Walmart"); // false
matches = characterRunAutomaton.run("Wal*mart"); // true
matches = characterRunAutomaton.run("Wal\\*mart"); // false
matches = characterRunAutomaton.run("Waldomart"); // false
```